# Is it ok to update template in real time with jquery in django?

Tags: jquery, django

I have a script that makes an ajax request for every 2 seconds in my django template. This script is basically calling `cpu_view` function from `views.py` every 2 seconds and this function updates the data needed to populate my django table.

Everything's working fine except that the page or specifically the html content of the page refreshes everytime including all the buttons which make the page looks kind of weird IMO. So I thought maybe there's a better way of doing this. Basically, what I'm trying to do here is to create a small monitoring application for my servers.

Any advice or help is appreciated.

Template **cpu.html**

```
{# server/templates/server/table.html #}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>List of persons</title>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '/server/jquery-3.4.1.js' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function executeQuery() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '/server/cpu',
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("html").html(data)
                    }
                });
            }
            setInterval(executeQuery, 2000);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% render_table table %}
    </body>

</html>
```

**views.py**

```
def cpu_view(request):
    output = []
    listServers = Serveurs.objects.all()

    for x in get_proc_output():
        pid = x.get('pid')
        for y in get_netstat_output():
            if pid in y.values():
                output.append({**x,**y})

    for i in listServers:
        for j in output:
            if i.port in j.values():
                j['type_server'] = i.type_du_serveur

    table = TableServeur(output)
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'server/table.html', {'table': table})
```

Comment: You should only render a fragment of the page and insert that into the relevant part in your success function, rather than the whole thing.

Comment: yeah I thought about doing this, but because I use django_tables2 to populate my data, I didn't find any answer to use it with ajax request @DanielRoseman

Comment: I don't understand what that has to do with anything. It will still be rendering HTML elements such as divs, you can select the ones you want.

Comment: What @DanielRoseman is saying is you need two views and two templates: one for the entire page and one that's queried by your jQuery request and returns partial html. You can optimise this by having one view that checks if the request.is_ajax() depending on which it returns the partial html of the full html and use {% include %} to reuse the partial template in the full page template.